# How to avoid Flutter FutureBuilder with UniqueKey flickering when SetState() is called?

Tags: flutter

I have a `PageView` (parent PageView) and each of its pages is a `StatefulWidget` that returns `FutureBuilder`. The `FutureBuilder` itself will return a `PageView`(child PageView), too. Because I want both parent and child `PageView` to keep page, so both parent and child widget are implemented with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

Each page is assigned a `UniqueKey` because the pages are dynamic, meaning users can delete some pages or add pages. However when `SetState()` is called, there're two problems: 1 the whole page flickers; 2 the child `PageView` jumps back to page at index 0.

If I don't use `UniqueKey`, these two issues disappear. But then after adding or deleting pages, you can't refresh the pages.

Any advice are appreciated, thanks!

Codes that shows the Flickering:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Bar(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  List<Widget> pages;

  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pages = [
      Center(child: PageWithFutureBuilder(key: UniqueKey())),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          PageWithFutureBuilder(key: UniqueKey()),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              refresh();
            },
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.refresh,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ];
    return PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children: pages,
    );
  }

  void refresh() async {
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class PageWithFutureBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  PageWithFutureBuilder({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PageWithFutureBuilderState();
}

Future test() async {
  return;
}

class _PageWithFutureBuilderState extends State<PageWithFutureBuilder> {
  Future future;
  @override
  void initState() {
    future = test();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      builder: (ocntext, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(child: Text('test text'));
        } else
          return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Swipe to the 2nd page, then click on the button, you'll see the flickering. As to the codes of `jumping back to page at index 0`, they're too complex to put here, and it's probably the same reason with the flickering.

Comment: Please share your code. Check the guidelines for tips on improving your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday and you will get the same answers: post your code and we will check it. Without seeing your code... there is no way to tell you what to improve.

Comment: @nvoigt  Yesterday the question was unclear, so I thought it'd be better if I took it down before I explore and get a better understanding of my own codes. Sorry about that.

Comment: @João Soares Example codes are updated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the right solution. Basically it's caused by using a wrong `Key`. Using a `UniqueKey` makes Flutter regarding the child widget as different so it re-initialized new child widget every time it rebuilds. Hence the flickering and jumping back to page at index 0.

Instead of using a `UniqueKey`, use a value key. In my case each of my child parent has a unique `object ID`, so I use `Key(objectID)` as the key. So when `SetState()` get called, flutter will know some widgets can be reused since they have the same key, so the flickering disappears and it won't jump back to page at index 0.